How can i copy a file to azure app service bin directory using powershell?
I have a file that i want to copy to the bin directory of an azure app service.
Currently i do this manually , but i want to do it automatically.
I have found this so far
  $localFiles = Get-ChildItem $tempFolder

  $accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webappName
 
$localFiles | % {
Write-Host "Uploading $($_.Name)" -NoNewline
Upload-FileToWebApp $accessToken $webappName $_.Name $_.FullName 
Write-Host -f Green " [Done]"
}

How can i do this ? where do i even start ?

Where does you file exist? can you please provide some more information.

the file is on the c:\ drive of the local machine and i want to copy it to the bin directory of my app service

If it is in local one cannot use automation, If the file is Azure Storage then one can do azure automation.

I think you can using az cli , but im not quite sure how ... ?

you just put that script in ci/cd job , thats what i mean by automation
